# how to set backroundColor of a UIlabel based on json response Value?

Tags: json, swift, uicolor, rest

I have a Json Data which holds UIColor values as String, and I want to change the backgoundColor of my Label based on those values, but don't know how to. is there any way to do this?

here is the json data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "black",
    "colorLeft": "000000",
    "colorRight": "000000",
    "type": 1,
    "leftBrightness": 0.0,
    "rightBrightness": 0.0
}
```

and here is my Color Class:

```
class ColorCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var colorName: UILabel!
    
    var colorLeft: String!
    var colorRight: String!
    var type: Int!
    var leftBrightness: Double!
    var rightBrightness: Double!
    
    func configureCell(for data: Colors) {
        self.colorName.text = data.title
    }
    func setColor(for data: Colors) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        self.colorLeft = data.colorLeft
        self.colorRight = data.colorRight
        self.type = data.type
        self.leftBrightness = data.leftBrightness
        self.rightBrightness = data.rightBrightness
        
        uicol
    }
}
```

and this is what I have done so far.

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: @Rob, The only issue i have that i cannot change the background color of my label based on these values from json data. .

Comment: @O_S What exactly you want to achieve? How the label should look like in the end?

Comment: So If I'm not mistaken, you do want to add gradient color to the label's background, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line to set background colour of your label from a string.

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "your colour name")
```

According to your response :-

```
colorName.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: self.colorLeft)
```

Comment: as you can see, there are more attributes to identify the color, not just " colorLeft ". thanks tho..

Answer (score 0):

```
class ColorCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var colorName: UILabel!
    
    var colorLeft: String!
    var colorRight: String!
    var type: Int!
    var leftBrightness: Double!
    var rightBrightness: Double!
    
    func configureCell(for data: Colors) {
        self.colorName.text = data.title
    }
    func setColor(for data: Colors) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        self.colorLeft = data.colorLeft
        self.colorRight = data.colorRight
        self.type = data.type
        self.leftBrightness = data.leftBrightness
        self.rightBrightness = data.rightBrightness
        
        
        let clrLeft = UIColor(hex: "#"+self.colorLeft)!
        let clrRight = UIColor(hex: "#"+self.colorRight)!
        
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = colorName.bounds
        gradient.colors = [clrLeft.cgColor, clrRight.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        colorName.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hex: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hexColor = String(hex[start...])

            if hexColor.count == 8 {
                let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Check This for reference..

[Tutorial 01](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor)
[Tutorial 02](https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/how-to-create-gradient-color-using-cagradientlayer/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.. .

```
extension UIColor {
     convenience init(color: String, brightness: String) {
     let scanBrightness = Scanner(string: String(describing: brightness))
     let scanColor = Scanner(string: color)
    
     scanBrightness.scanLocation = 0
     scanColor.scanLocation = 0
    
     var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
     scanBrightness.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
     scanColor.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
     let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
     let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
     let b = rgbValue & 0xff
    
     self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff, green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff, blue: 
               CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1)
     }
  }
```

and inside Cell:

```
 func configureCell(for data: Colors) {
       self.colorName.text = data.title
       self.type = data.type
       
       self.colorLeft = data.colorLeft
       self.colorRight = data.colorRight
       
       self.brightnessLeft = data.leftBrightness
       self.brightnessRight = data.rightBrightness
       
      
       self.rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(color: colorRight, brightness: String(describing: brightnessRight))
       self.leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(color: colorLeft, brightness: String(describing: brightnessLeft))
   }
```